# How to redirect url from a website with a blank sever to another website

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have an old website which i deleted everything on the sever. Now i want to redirect it to the new website. And i want it to be like this:

1.old.com => new.com

2.old.com/product=>new.com/product

Just these 2 redirects. I tried to install the prestashop on the old website to redirect.I tried to add this to the .httaccess ( i installed the prestashop on the blank sever) but it did not work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301]
```

Please help me. Thank you a lot

Comment: "Just these 2 redirects." - literally just those "2 redirects", or do you really want to redirect `old.com/<any-product>` to `new.com/<any-product>`? "it did not work" - please describe more precisely in what way it did not work? The wrong redirect? No redirect at all? An error?

Comment: Just that 2 redirect. Because i delete everything on the sever( accidentally, i am dumb). So i tried to upload some new file with a brand new .httaccess to redirect these two to my new site (luckily it was an old site)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add %{REQUEST_URI} parameter.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Comment: But it only work with the first one is that correct. Every url on the old.com will become the new.com, right?

Comment: @Newbie Yes,it does not apply if there are REQUEST_URI parameters after the domain name

Comment: @Plantour What do you mean by "it does not apply if there are REQUEST_URI parameters after the domain name"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you ask for exactly two redirections. So you should implement exactly two redirections:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://new.example.com/ [R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^/product/?$ https://new.example.com/product [R=301,END]
```

This relies on the name resolutions for old.example.com and new.example.com to point to different systems. If both names resolve to the same system then you need to add a condition to prevent a redirection loop:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://new.example.com/ [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/product/?$ https://new.example.com/product [R=301,END]
```

Any other request will then result in a 404 status, assuming that the old host name is still served by some other system.

In general I would recommend to implement such rules in the actual http server's configuration of the host "old.example.com" instead of using a distributed configuration file (".htaccess").